# Implementing Events in a Base Class

Tags: vb.net, oop, events

Consider the following objects:

```
Public MustInherit Class FileRepository

    Public MustOverride Sub SaveStringToFile(ByVal FileText As String, ByVal FilePath As String)

    Public Event FileSaved(ByRef sender As Object, ByVal EventArgs As EventArgs)

End Class

Public Class XMLFileRepository
    Inherits FileRepository

    Public Overrides Sub SaveStringToFile(ByVal FileText As String, ByVal FilePath As String)

    End Sub

    Private Sub XMLFileRepository_FileSaved(ByRef sender As Object, ByVal EventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.FileSaved

    End Sub
End Class
```

I want my base class to raise the `FileSaved` event in it's implentation of `SaveStringToFile` once it's saved the file.  However in VB.NET you can't have a derived class raise a base classes event.  I suppose I can treat `XMLFileRepository_FileSaved` as a standard function call and have my `SaveStringToFile` implementation call it directly but I think I'm approaching the problem the wrong way.  Any help would be great!

Comment: Could you use an interface instead? Another option might be to write a wrapper-method `RaiseFileSaved(Object, EventArgs)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an overridable sub in your base class that raises the base classes FileSaved-Event:

```
Public MustInherit Class FileRepository

    Public MustOverride Sub SaveStringToFile(ByVal FileText As String, ByVal FilePath As String)

    Public Event FileSaved(ByVal FileText As String, ByVal FilePath As String)

    Protected Overridable Sub OnFileSaved(ByVal FileText As String, ByVal FilePath As String)
        RaiseEvent FileSaved(FileText, FilePath)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class XMLFileRepository
    Inherits FileRepository

    Public Overrides Sub SaveStringToFile(ByVal FileText As String, ByVal FilePath As String)
        MyBase.OnFileSaved(FileText, FilePath)
    End Sub

    Private Sub XMLFileRepository_FileSaved(ByVal FileText As String, ByVal FilePath As String) Handles MyBase.FileSaved

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: To follow the .NET guidelines, name the method OnFileSaved.

Comment: in the calling code, i instantiate the derived class WITHEVENTS but i cant add a handler because the derived class raises no events.  Thoughts?